# SSL certification error in python while making requests

Tags: python, ssl, python-requests, gspread

I am using gspread to access google spreadsheet but it is showing SSLError.

Similar thing is happening when I am using requests library.

```py
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials

scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds',
         'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']

credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('credentials.json', scope)

gc = gspread.authorize(credentials)`
```

The error is :

```py
SSLCertVerificationError                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-87ec55398e31> in <module>
      7 credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('credentials.json', scope)
      8 
----> 9 gc = gspread.authorize(credentials)


SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1051)
```

Comment: Please provide use your code. We cannot help without heaving more details.

Comment: "unable to get local issuer certificate" : a certificate you received is signed by a CA you do not trust, as you do not have the CA certificate. So you need to add the relevant CA certificate to your trust store so that remote certificate can be verified.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek How can we add them if you can shed some light over that part also.

Comment: A quick search for `CA` errors involving `gspread` shows a [closed GitHub issue](https://github.com/burnash/gspread/issues/223) with some suggestions that maybe helpful. However, I'd advise using a `venv` for testing anything suggested there as there's some _less than good_ security practices suggested to resolve this. The TLDR version is that `certifi` is usually the underlining cause of headaches. Oh and the other suggestion, found on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31793275/2632107), looks promising as far as modifying `venv` certs.

Comment: I already answered this here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56549510/8538812

Answer (score 0):

It works for me with `requests == 2.21.0` and `certifi == 2018.11.29` so first thing I'd check is if the versions you have are older (especially `certifi`).

Also, if this is caused by *certifi*, you should be able to work around by resetting the trust store used by *requests* to shared system trust store, you can find the path by running:

```sh
python3 -c 'import ssl; print(ssl.get_default_verify_paths())'
```

look for value of `cafile` or `openssl_cafile` and then (replace `$cafile` with the value obtained):

```sh
export REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE=$cafile
```

See also [this bug](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/issues/2966).